# How do I query MongoID in ruby with any_of and any_in?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have some Requests that looks like this.

```
Request: 1
assigned_id: xyz
assigned_2_id: nil
check_number: 1234
check_number_helper: nil

Request: 2
assigned_id: abc
assigned_2_id: xyz
check_number: 3344
check_number_helper: 1234

Request: 3
assigned_id: xyz
assigned_2_id: ffg
check_number: 1234
check_number_helper: 6678

Request: 4
assigned_id: xyz
assigned_2_id: ffg
check_number: 7777
check_number_helper: 6678
```

I need to find every Request where the assigned_id or assigned_2_id is xyz **AND** the check_number or check_number_helper is 1234

I tried the following but it returns all matches assigned_id, assigned_2_id, check_number, and check_number_helper (so in the data above it returns all Requests) as it matches at least one field.

```
Request.any_of({:assigned_2_id => assigned_id.to_s}, {:assigned_id => assigned_id.to_s}).any_of({:check_number => check_num}, {:check_number_helper => check_num}).asc(:timestamp_requested)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you were looking for. But closes question I could find. And the only solution I could come up with (and so anyone gets some help). Here's what I ended up with:

```
Modal.all_of({visibility: true}, {"$or" => query})
```

This seems to correctly return anything that is 'visibility: true' AND anything that is in my or selectors:

```
query = [{:songs.gte => 1},{:books.gte => 1}]
```